# How to convert accuracy of DEM from 5 decimal places to 2

Tags: dem, spatial-analyst

I had a csv dataset comprising of regular points containing elevation "z-values". I interpolated this using ESRI´s spatial analyst using the IDW method to produce a continuous raster surface. I set the resolution at 12,5 meters, because the points were 12,5 meters apart.

I now have a raster image which gives me values with 5 decimal places. The original data only had 2 decimal places.

My question is...should I round this up to 2 decimal places, because having this level of accuracy doesn´t reflect the absolute accuracy of the image. If I should round up the values, how/with which tool would I do it?

thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally you're right, you shouldn't have excess decimal places because it gives [False Precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision). I've seen datasets with so many decimal places they're measuring down to the 10's of nanometers!

Unfortunately there's a long thread on the ESRI forums which suggests that ArcGIS at least can't do this - http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=243049

However, you can truncate (via ROUND, CEIL or FLOOR) the decimals entirely which might be a better option given they're interpolated anyway.